# I cannot run a .py file in cmd on windows 10, or in the terminal in kali linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, command-prompt

Lets just start by saying I am a complete greenhorn to python and programming altogether but I really do want to learn so if you could try and use terms a beginner would understand that would help me a lot.
OK After getting incredibly frustrated googling how to use python in kali Linux couldn't run a file there either, I downloaded it on My Windows 10 OS then I made a basic script that looks like

```
#! /usr/bin/python
a = 122
b = 344
print a + b
```

very simple right. saved it as math.py and went the the cmd prompt (because wikki how told me to) then typed in the location of math py :

```
 cd C:\Users\Mitchel\Documents
```

I read a question on here that told me to use cd to enter the location. python responded with :

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
cd C:\Users\Mitchel\Documents
   ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

so I decided to go to try going to the next step anyways and just typed

```
python math.py
```

and got the same error. I tried double clicking the file, I tried "open with" and clicking python. I want to know I can type code in notepad or notepad++ and test it before I start because its reall hard to actually write the code in the command prompt itself.

Comment: it looks like you run `python` and then you use `cd` but `cd` is not `python` command but cmd/terminal command.

Comment: run `cmd.exe` and then use `cd` - it seems that now you run `python.exe`, not `cmd.exe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are commands to enter at your system's command prompt, but you are entering them in the Python interpreter. Most tutorials assume that you know how to get around your system's terminal. See below for a demonstration.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\TigerhawkT3>cd
C:\Users\TigerhawkT3

C:\Users\TigerhawkT3>cd ..

C:\Users>py -c "print(1+2)"
3

C:\Users>py
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> cd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'cd' is not defined
>>> cd ..
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    cd ..
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> py -c "print(1+2)"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    py -c "print(1+2)"
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print(1+2)
3
>>>
```

Comment: Ok just so everyone else whos as bad at this as I am gets it in the future. Open command prompt DO NOT GO INTO PYTHON, type "cd C:\Users\Mitchel\Documents" (that's where the file is, to find what to type go the the .py file right click and press properties it will start with "c:\Users") and then type Python filename.py (replace file name with your files actual name) Thankyou guys. Got a smile on my face ive been stuck on something so stupid